# how can I write version number from commit msg to file?

Tags: git

I want to parse version number from commit message and write it to file, then save it in repo.

I wrote post-commit hook:

```
grep -E "\[(\S+)\]" .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG > version
git commit --amend --no-verify
```

after I make commit, I have version number in file, but there's some problem with commit amend:

```
Too many errors from stdin
error: There was a problem with the editor 'editor'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
[1.0.4a2jen 46b9dad] [test666]
 3 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

i tried to set core.editor as "nano", result is the same, except it says "There was a problem with the editor 'nano'"
What should I do?

Comment: the problem was that "--no-verify" key skips only pre-commit and commit-msg hooks, but not post-commit, so every time "git commit --amend" runs it calls the post-commit script and there's a loop. The solution is to disable post-commit hook before amending commit:  ```chmod -x .git/hooks/post-commit
git commit --amend --no-verify --no-edit
chmod +x .git/hooks/post-commit
```